# How to create a Python class

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working on a project and didn't do a good example of what I needed help with earlier so my thread was closed. What I need help doing is creating a class in Python that defines penny as an object, so later on I can go back in and change it to nickel, dime, quarter, etc, I have the basic idea of how to create it just want to make sure I'm on the right track or if I've completely vered off. In this I need to create the classes and then figure out how to add them by weight, and by height. In the beginning you will be asked to enter a number to go to a class and enter how many of those objects you have and add up the number.

[image]

This gives you an idea of what I've started to put together for the penny class that's all the data I need to have for the class just want to make sure I set it up correctly. Also how do I go about importing this into a new class like Quarter()

Comment: -1 for posting a screenshot instead of just cutting and pasting the code.

Comment: I thought the screen shot would be the easiest way to understand because Python is so sensative. sorry

Comment: why are you using a class for this exactly? this seems like its just data ... typically classes incorporate actions as well

Comment: I think you can only have a single __init__ method in your python class.

Comment: @RobertMoskal you can have 2 ... only the last one will be used though ...

Comment: Hmm... do you want to have more than one `Penny`?  would you ever want a `some_pennies = [my_penny, your_penny]`?  Classes describe *kinds* of things;  `class Penny...` describes in python all of the things that *are `Penny`s*.  the class of `123` is `int`; the class of `"Hello World"` is `str`.  What are the things who's class is `Penny`?  Explaining how you hope to use this class (with example code) will help us steer you toward a helpful answer.

Comment: Ha, true.  Thats' why I love me those languages that are just hashtables full of functions.

Comment: This one is slightly different because I am creating one for each I need a penny, quarter, nickel, and dime so i just figured i would make the one class and than be able to copy it somehow i'm in the process of learning how to copy a class. All in all the program is going to ask you to input input a number for a specific class like 1 for penny than ask how many coins, than with that it will add the amount total in weight and the total in height and tell you. Very odd program but something I have to do

Answer (score 8):

You probably want something like a Coin class for penny, nickel, dime, quarter to inherit from. Also you should only have one init method

```
class Coin():
    def __init__(self,weight,height):
        self.weight = weight
        self.height = height

class Penny(Coin):
    def __init__(self):
        Coin.__init__(self,2.5,1.52)
```

Comment: you don't need `class Foo():`,  In python2 use `class Foo(object):` or in python 3 just `class Foo:` (with no parens at all).  It's not a problem, but looks sort of off.

Comment: you can do `class Foo:` in python2 also (at least in 2.6)

Answer (score 2):

I would just use a dictionary for this since it only encapsulates data:

```
coin_dict = {1:(2.5,1.52),5:(nickle_weight,nickle_height),10:...}

weight,height = coin_dict[1]
```

Typically you would use a class if you wanted to encapsulate actions with data... or if your data gets very complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could have a parent class named Coin with a set of attributes, weight and height, depending on what you want to use it for. And then inherit from her to create a Penny or another coins.

```
class Coin:
     def __init__(self, height, weight):
         self.height = height
         self.weight = weight

class Penny(Coin):
      self.color = "bronze"
```

and go on from there. Then you can create a list and fill them with objects from the Penny, or Coin class.

Answer (score 0):

Classes are a great way to represent real world data/objects in a digital format.

Before creating your class think about what you need it to do. You will want it to be reusable and flexible. In your case would creating a penny class be best or would a coin class be better? If you create a penny class you will have to create a nickel class and a dime class and so on. If you create a coin class you only have to instantiate a new one for each new type of coin.

A class can also only have one `__init__` method. You can declare many attributes in on method though. For example:

```
class Pet:
    def __init__(self, name, species):
        self.name = name
        self.species = species
```